# How to analyze android kernel panic?

Tags: android, kernel, panic

i develop a small embeded android system.
and, sometimes suffer from kernel panics.

checked the `tombstone` log, but it is difficult to analyze the exact cause.
also, sometimes there is no log.

is there a way to get the cause of android kernel panics
and crash dumps instead of logs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For android, you find the backtrace for kernel panic if you reboot your device, you check

```
cat /proc/last_kmsg
```

or

```
cat /sys/fs/pstore/console-ramoops-0
```